# design problem for stream of events having buy and sell data for users

Tags: java, events, system-design

Problem description: There is a queue always having data for customers buy and sell of some assets. Now the output that I am looking is to calculate the profit and loss of each customer, also the entity is like keep on changing the price like stocks.
Buy events gives you all meta data like amount bought and the price it bought. Sell event give data about selling amount and cost of sell. Profit and loss formula is similar as the (marketcost-originalcost)/original cost.
Now the problem is I am handling the events sequentially and its not giving me freedom of async event consumption, Can anyone suggest what can be the best way to design this?

Answer (score -2):

Try a concurrent operation:
Check this:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Examplied, it works like this:>

```
    AnEntity aeS = new AnEntity();
    aeS.fieldA = "";
    aeS.fieldB = "";
    
    Executor exec = new Executor() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Runnable command) {
            System.out.println("Typed first");
            if(aeS.fieldA.isEmpty())aeS.fieldA="Operating";
            else if(aeS.fieldB.isEmpty())aeS.fieldB="Operating";
            command.run();
        }
    };
    exec.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(aeS.fieldA.isEmpty())aeS.fieldA="...in operation code.";
            System.out.println("aeS.fieldA=" +aeS.fieldA);
            aeS.fieldA="Done";
            System.out.println("aeS.fieldA=" +aeS.fieldA);
        }
    });
    exec.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(aeS.fieldB.isEmpty())aeS.fieldB="...in operation code.";
            System.out.println("aeS.fieldB=" +aeS.fieldB);
            aeS.fieldB="Done";
            System.out.println("aeS.fieldB=" +aeS.fieldB);
        }
    });
```

Output:

> Typed first
>
> aeS.fieldA=Operating
>
> aeS.fieldA=Done
>
> Typed first
>
> aeS.fieldB=Operating
>
> aeS.fieldB=Done